# total variation of a pressure field with support on the elements of a complex structure

Tags: matlab, optimization, finite-element-analysis, fluid-dynamics

I am trying to develop a mathematical method to calculate the 
pressure field on offshore structures.

We are given the resultant force on the structure F, and a pressure 
profile model `pi = p0 dot(ni,nF)` that our solution should follow. Where:

- `{pi}_{i=1}^{Nel}` are the pressures defined in the elements of the structure (see [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhURt.jpg));
- `ni` are the outward normals of the elements (dot is the scalar prod)
- `Ai` are element areas;
- `nf=F/|F|`;
- `p0` is the effective pressure of the model.

I am using an optimazition algorithm using an objective function with two terms:

```
PHI = \alpha * ||F-F_rec ||_2^2 + \Sum_i (p0*dot(ni,nF) - pi)^2
```

to get the figures I am showing. where `F_rec = \sum_i pi Ai ni`.

I would like to add a new term in the objective accounting for continuity in the pressure field. So far I have been thinking in a third term like:

```
\beta * \sum_i 1/3(\sum_{j=neig(i) (pi*dot(nj,nF) - pj*dot(ni,nF))^2})
```

Where `\alpha` and `\beta` are constants controlling the importance of each term in the objective.

Other possibility is that the third term accounts for the total variation of the
pressure field (or maybe `pi/dot(ni,nF)` field). Do you have any idea of how I can define a third term measuring the total variation in a surface like this?

Thanks a lot!